# Pass model errors through controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model

I have 2 models - Project and Review. Project has_many reviews and Review belong_to Project. When I open project (**show** REST action) I can add review for it. But the controller which accept data from form and save it is different on project(show action in ProjectsController, create action of Review in ReviewsController).

Problem is that I don't understand how render errors of Review model. If I have 1 controller I do something like this:

```
if @project.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html {redirect_to :back, :notice => I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.project.added")}
  end
else
  render :action => :show
end
```

And rails render error messages under each form field, that has errors. Flash messages don't accepted.

Comment: hi! is that code in the reviews controller? if it is, shouldn't that be `@review.save`?

Comment: No, it just example. In reviews controlelr of course @review.save

Comment: sorry, i still don't get what you want. you may need to add more details.

Comment: What kind of details? 2 models, 2 controllers. If I submit form of review create with invalid data they go to create action of reviews controller. What I should render or redirect if model has validate errors?

Answer (score 1):

in your reviews controller, try the following

```
def create
  @project = Project.find... # fetch the project
  @review = @project.reviews.build params[:review]
  @review.save

  render template: 'projects/show'
end
```

in the project page, check for `@review` and if it has errors

```
# app/views/projects/show.html.erb
<% if @review && @review.errors.any? %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's work, but maybe you can help me with another problem? Form for adding review I creating this way: **form_for([@project, Review.new], :validate => true, :remote => true)** and I don't write any code for checking if model has errors or not in each form. In initializer I have proc, that generating this errors (default behaviour of client-side validation gem). It's work with server side validations too. The question is: **Is it possible follow this convention in my case?**

Comment: yep it is possible. i've tried `client_side_validation` gem on associations before.  since you're using remote, you can add a respond_to block to the create action and add a create.js.erb file.

Comment: I meen, if I disable JavaScript in my browser, I can't see any error messages anymore.

Comment: sorry, i don't get what you mean.  you said you're using client side validations which relies on javascript to show the error messages but you want to disable javascript?

Comment: Don't look at gem name :) It has initializer, that render errors with or without javascript. It work with simple (not nested forms). I disabled javascript, but errors still rendering. And I haven't any code for it. You can find it in /config/initializer/client_side_validation.rb

Comment: i dont think you can use client side validation without js.  here's the initializer file and there's no option to use it without javascript https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/blob/3-2-stable/lib/generators/templates/client_side_validations/initializer.rb

Comment: Hmm, but what renders errors? If I comment initializer code, errors stop rendering. Javascript disable of course.

Comment: without js, the gem wont work because it uses ajax to check the validations.

Comment: ajax only for validates, that cannot be done with javascript, such as unique, etc. Other validates writes js code when page rendering.